# Linear Programming Improve Overlap

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools

Is there a way to introduce an overlap objective to this linear programming problem?

Simplified Example:

In my problem, each variable represents a "task" that needs to be completed a certain number of times. When we need to do a "task" it works better if we can have multiple people do that "task" at the same time.

```
Person 1 Constraint 1: a1 + b1 >= 5
Person 1 Constraint 2: c1 + d1 >= 2
...
Person 2 Constraint 1: a2 + e2 >= 2
Person 2 Constraint 2: f2 + g2 >= 1
...
Person N

Objective 1: Minimize Overall Cost
Objective 2: Maximize Overlap
```

So in the above example choosing a1 instead of b1 would be ideal since it would overlap with a2).

I'm currently using Google OR Tools which only supports 1 objective (as far as I can tell), so I'm hoping I can somehow translate the 2nd objective into a sub-objective of #1.

i.e (Minimize Cost Equation * 100000000) + (-1 * Maximize Overlap Equation)

Comment: You are close. Often this is done by weighting the different objectives. I.e. `MIN 1000*Cost - 1*Overlap`, where `Cost` and `Overlap` are variables,

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen - Thanks. Do you have any idea how I can define a function for overlap?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then that may not be very simple. You need to count things and then put more emphasis on larger counts. Some tricks that are possible: use quadratic values, or maximize a minimum count. There may be other possibilities to model this also: put a penalty on small counts etc.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen - Yes, you seem to be understanding my question correctly (sorry for not being clear). Is there a trick to perform counting?

Comment: Depends on the details. E.g. very different for continuous time opposed to discrete time (time slots).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen My problem isn't time-bound at all does that make a difference? Ideally I'd just say Minimize(distinct count of tasks in this case 2 - a and b) but I can't seem to figure out how to get the count.

Comment: In general this is a multi-objective optimization problem. There are free tools for these types of problems, for instance [PolySCIP](http://polyscip.zib.de/)